# Model properties replace space with &nbsp ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I type "fa fa-pencil-square-o" code it works fine, but when I use like class="@Model[i].Icon"  the icon is disappearing when I inspect it is showing like "fa&nbspfa-pencil-square-o"

```
@model List<Muksab.Models.AboutModel>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@for (int j = 0; j <= Model.Count(); j++)
{

    <div class="row">
        @for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            if (j <= Model.Count())
            {
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="single-about-content">
                        <div class="icon round-border tran3s">
                            <i class="@Model[i].Icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>

                        <h5><a href="#" class="tran3s">@Model[i].Services</a></h5>
                        <p>@Model[i].ServicesDescr</p>
                        <a href="#" class="more tran3s hvr-bounce-to-right">More Details</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                j++;
            }

        }

    </div>
}
```

Comment: you can just use <i class="@Html.raw(Model[i].Icon)" aria-hidden="true"></i>

Comment: i tried <i class="@Html.raw(Model[i].Icon)" aria-hidden="true"></i>  , not working.from yesterday i am in problem please any one help me out.

Comment: can you please tell me the output after using html.raw ..... Also when you're fetching it how you're putting it into Model[i].icon

Comment: when its getting converted escape character is occuring instead of that space so better use without space in the class name. It will be ok. For example - fa fa need to be changed to fafa

Comment: it was the problem of copy past.when i type it is working fine but when i do copy past it is not working, i don't why. thank you all